# how to get row values when checkbox is checked in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

before I asked this I did some checking around to make sure that this doesn't turn out to be a duplicate and ways to get the row values from a row that has a checkbox in its template field...but I can't seem to get it working...So far I have tried

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Entities NW = new Entities();

        var customers =
            from c in NW.Customers
            where (c.ContactName.StartsWith("Ma") || c.ContactName.StartsWith("An")
            || c.ContactName.StartsWith("T")
            || c.ContactName.StartsWith("V")
            )
            orderby c.ContactName ascending
            select new
            {
                c.CustomerID,
                c.ContactName,
                c.CompanyName,
                c.City
            };

        gv1.DataSource = customers.ToList();
        gv1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("CB") as CheckBox);
                if (chkRow.Checked)
                {
                    Label1.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have stepped through the button click event and when it gets to

> if (chkRow.Checked)

its showing as null and skips over it..

my markup is

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="SkyBlue" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Yellow" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CB" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

when I look at the source after I run, the checkboxes are all named differently than what I gave them the ID of "CB", attached is the pic of the source when its running

[image: Source when ran]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GridView` should have more columns, because you are referencing `Cell[2]` in your code.

You might try to use `row` object to look for your control:

```
CheckBox chkRow = (row.FindControl("CB") as CheckBox);
```

Comment: After looking at your answer I chopped up some the of the code and got rid of the if statements and changed my Checkbox to match yours and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Actually, I thought it worked, but it just grabs any control that it finds and populates the Label.

Comment: What do you mean by "any control"? Do you have multiple controls named "CB" in one single row?

Comment: No, whats happening is that it goes to the very last row in the gridview and selects the value from the 2nd cell. That happens whether I check a checkbox or not and when I add the if statement to back to see if its checked, it just goes over the if the statement

Comment: Is it possible that your label's `Text` is just overwritten several times in your loop and you see the latest value?

Comment: I just double checked that and its not being overwritten...I put a watch on the chkRow and stepped through it and its never finding a checked control... even when I have one checked

Comment: I'm using the NorthWind database for this, so if its not much of a hassle, then everything can be replicated with the code that I provided

Comment: If the code you provide here is complete, than you should consider using `Page.IsPostback` in your `Page_Load()` event handler, for you are resetting your binding every time you load the page, hence rendering all the checkboxes to false. If I do so, it works on my side (I just copied your code to a new ASP.NET app in my VS).

Comment: ohhhh, yea. You are right, it never even dawned on me that it was resetting on a postback. I added the !isPostBack and it works perfectly. Thanks for sticking through with me on this.